How to resolve AWS R53 DNS error not permitted in zone
I am using cloudformation to create a record set in R53 for my API.
I have this custom domain name for my API setup successfully.
my-uat-tests.init.dev01.svc.com

I already have Amazon issued certificate setup in my account with Key algorithm "RSA 2048".
The Domain name for the certificate is "my-uat-tests.init.dev01.svc.com"
When I tried to create R53 record set, I am getting the below error.
[RRSet with DNS name my-uat-tests.init.dev01.svc.com. is not permitted in zone int.dev01.svc.com.]
This is my R53 record set block.
APIDnsEntry:
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
  Properties:
    AliasTarget:
      DNSName: "my-uat-tests.init.dev01.svc.com"
      EvaluateTargetHealth: false
      HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZoneId
    Comment: !Sub 'DNS name for ${AppNameForResources} API'
    HostedZoneName: !Ref HostedZoneName
    Name: "my-uat-tests.init.dev01.svc.com"
    Type: A

I can't seem to figure out what mistake I am doing here.
Any help is much appreciated.

Add dots at the end of the HostedZoneName and Name.
Replace "APIGateway" with the logical ID of your API Gateway resource in the CloudFormation template.
APIDnsEntry:
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
  Properties:
    AliasTarget:
      DNSName: !GetAtt APIGateway.RegionalDomainName
      EvaluateTargetHealth: false
      HostedZoneId: !GetAtt APIGateway.RegionalHostedZoneId
    Comment: !Sub 'DNS name for ${AppNameForResources} API'
    HostedZoneName: "init.dev01.svc.com."
    Name: "my-uat-tests.init.dev01.svc.com."
    Type: A

Also, in this part of the error; is not permitted in zone int.dev01.svc.com. it shows int and not init.
They will have to match one way or the other.
